# How do I move/copy files in s3 using boto3 asynchronously?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I understand using boto3 Object.copy_from(...) uses threads but is not asynchronous.  Is it possible to make this call asynchronous?  If not, is there another way to accomplish this using boto3?  I'm finding that moving hundreds/thousands of files is fine, but when i'm processing 100's of thousands of files it gets extremely slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following. You can copy into a python file and run it from the command line. I have a PC with 8 cores, so it's faster than my little EC2 instance with 1 VPC.

It uses the `multiprocessing` library, so you'd want to read up on that if you aren't familiar. It's relatively straightforward. There's a batch delete that I've commented out because you really don't want to accidentally delete the wrong directory. You can use whatever methods you want to list the keys or iterate through the objects, but this works for me.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
from itertools import repeat
import boto3
import os
import math

s3sc = boto3.client('s3')
s3sr = boto3.resource('s3')
num_proc = os.cpu_count()


def get_list_of_keys_from_prefix(bucket, prefix):
    """gets list of keys for given bucket and prefix"""
    keys_list = []
    paginator = s3sr.meta.client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
    for page in paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix, Delimiter='/'):
        keys = [content['Key'] for content in page.get('Contents')]
        keys_list.extend(keys)
    if prefix in keys_list:
        keys_list.remove(prefix)
    return keys_list


def batch_delete_s3(keys_list, bucket):
    total_keys = len(keys_list)
    chunk_size = 1000
    num_batches = math.ceil(total_keys / chunk_size)
    for b in range(0, num_batches):
        batch_to_delete = []
        for k in keys_list[chunk_size * b:chunk_size * b + chunk_size]:
            batch_to_delete.append({'Key': k})
        s3sc.delete_objects(Bucket=bucket, Delete={'Objects': batch_to_delete, 'Quiet': True})


def copy_s3_to_s3(from_bucket, from_key, to_bucket, to_key):
    copy_source = {'Bucket': from_bucket, 'Key': from_key}
    s3sr.meta.client.copy(copy_source, to_bucket, to_key)


def upload_multiprocess(from_bucket, keys_list_from, to_bucket, keys_list_to, num_proc=4):
    with Pool(num_proc) as pool:
        r = pool.starmap(copy_s3_to_s3, zip(repeat(from_bucket), keys_list_from, repeat(to_bucket), keys_list_to), 15)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
    return r


if __name__ == '__main__':
    __spec__ = None

    from_bucket = 'from-bucket'
    from_prefix = 'from/prefix/'
    to_bucket = 'to-bucket'
    to_prefix = 'to/prefix/'

    keys_list_from = get_list_of_keys_from_prefix(from_bucket, from_prefix)
    keys_list_to = [to_prefix + k.rsplit('/')[-1] for k in keys_list_from]

    rs = upload_multiprocess(from_bucket, keys_list_from, to_bucket, keys_list_to, num_proc=num_proc)

    # batch_delete_s3(keys_list_from, from_bucket)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [aioboto3](https://github.com/terrycain/aioboto3). It is a third party library, not created by AWS, but it provides `asyncio` support for selected (not all) AWS API calls.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use boto3 along with python threads to handle such cases, In [AWS S3 Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/optimizing-performance.html#:%7E:text=your%20application%20can%20achieve%20at%20least%203%2C500%20PUT/COPY/POST/DELETE%20or%205%2C500%20GET/HEAD%20requests%20per%20second%20per%20prefix%20in%20a%20bucket.) they mentioned

> Your application can achieve at least 3,500 PUT/COPY/POST/DELETE or 5,500 GET/HEAD requests per second per prefix in a bucket.

So you can make 3500 uploads by one call, nothing can override this 3500 limit set by AWS.

By using threads you need just 300 (approx) calls.

It Takes 5 Hrs in Worst Case i.e considering that your files are large, will take 1 min for a file to upload on average.

**Note:** Running more threads consumes more resources on your machine. You must be sure that your machine has enough resources to support the maximum number of concurrent requests that you want.